# Why str has no __radd__ method in Python?

Tags: python, implementation

str has other methods like __rmod__, __rsub__ or __rmul__

int did have a __radd__ method

Weird, and I'd like to know why.

Example radd beeing called when first term HAS add method:

```
>>> class STR(str):
...     def __radd__(self, other):
...             print "jeje"
...             return other.__add__(self)
... 
>>> 'aaaaa' + STR('bbbbb')
jeje
'aaaaabbbbb'
```

Answer (score 5):

`__radd__` is used when the first term of the addition does not implement `__add__`.  In the case of `int`, addition is well defined by its mathematical definition, and so int tries to coerce the other term into a number.

with `str`, there is no such well defined meaning, and the developers of python have decided that there is no obvious need to have something + "a string".

Comment: are you sure? In the example added to the question \_\_radd__ is used and the first term do have \_\_add__.

Comment: In the specific case of str + STR, STR is a subclass of str, since that provides a more specific method, it is used in preference to str.__add__

Answer (score 2):

Types  only define methods that they use.  Since the only objects that can be added to strings are other strings or unicode objects, there is no need for a general `__radd__` method.  `__rmul__` allows you to duplicate strings:

```
>>> 4 * 'abc'
'abcabcabcabc'
```

I'm not sure why `__rmod__` is needed, but it is somehow related to formatting.  Perhaps it eases the implementation of formatting with a single argument, as in `"Hello %s" % 'world'`.  I'm not sure.  Contrary to your assertion, there is no `__rsub__` on str objects.

In short, those methods are only defined if they actually do something.